# Doctrine: How to store dynamic attributes

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to store dynamic attributes into the database.

Example:
Some user wants to create a profile with custom characteristics. This could be age, hobby, job, school or what else. Every user can set his own characteristic. On the server side this could look like:

```
    $characteristics = array(
        0 => array('age', 22),
        1 => array('hobby', 'php'),
        2 => array('food', 'pizza'),
    );
```

With this structure it is possible to read out the attribute itself and the value also I can easily add and remove attributes.

Now I want to store such data by doctrine.

The question is now how I do this best:

1. Persist the Array
2. JSON
3. XML
4. Other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, the best way would probably be to simply use an array.

Doctrine 2 has support for an "array" type: If you map a property with that type, it will get automatically serialized and deserialized into the database.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
class MyEntity {
    /** @Column(type="array") */
    private $attributes = array();

    public function setAttribute($name, $value) {
        $this->attributes[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getAttribute($name) {
        return $this->attributes[$name];
    }
}
```

An approach like this would allow you to easily store the attributes, and it would also abstract away the details of how it's stored, so if you wanted to change it in the future (for example, maybe to use an EAV table or such) you wouldn't need to change your other code as much.

Comment: Hi, I also would plan to make the arrays reusable. Forexample for some meta data this is quite good. Imagine you want to add some detail information to your images (location, camera, etc.) than it would be good if this structure is reusable. With arrays I just could delete the second value and save the raw array structure. The only contra is that the whole process has to get hardcoded. But I don't think there are better ways...

Comment: @mr1031011 it won't be very good, with custom attributes it might be best to use a separate search engine (like ElasticSearch) since those can handle documents with arbitrary fields quite well..

Comment: @Jani Hartikainen Have you some example of using this approach with ElasticSearch?

Comment: @KarolFiturski may be this helps but it's in russian: http://habrahabr.ru/post/229905/